# How create module from settings.gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I have this gradel.settings

```
rootProject.name = 'dwelow'
include 'common'
include 'cmr-service'
include 'web-service'
include 'web-test'
```

after adding them and running I want them to be created as modules ,is this possible?

Comment: IDE will set up it as multi-module project provided that these modules exists and are properly configured as Gradle multi-module projects. Check this article https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create  sub module from the settings.gradle. Each sub module should have separate **build.gradle** file. then only you can run application specific module.

From my side question why? would like to creates multiple module with in the application.

Comment: thanks a lot ,I just wanted it to be fast after writing names auto-create modules